# RabbitMQ Add Header in Fanout Exchange

Tags: rabbitmq

I have a fanout exchange (Fanout) linked to 2 other exchanges (A, B).

I would like the fanout exchange to add the message header "x-delay: 30000" before adding the message to exchange A.  Is there any way of doing this?  In the management console, in the "Add binding from this exchange" I've tried adding the Argument x-delay, 30000, Number but that doesn't seem to work.

I'm using RabbitMQ 3.8.19 and the management console plugin.

Clarification: Exchange A is a RabbitMQ Delayed Message Exchange.  Essentially I want messages on A to be delayed.

The obvious answer is to submit the delay on the initial message on the fanout exchange.  However, what I really want is to have A have a 30 second delay, B to have a 10 second delay, etc.  So I'd like to have that flexibility if RabbitMQ can support this at the fanout binding layer

Answer (score 1):

`x-delay:xxx` works only with the [rabbitmq-delayed-message-exchange](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-delayed-message-exchange)
it does not work with standard fanout exchange.

Comment: See my edits.  I am using a delayed message exchange